# Task.WhenAll ContinueWith deadlock

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, task, deadlock

I develop my mobile app in xamarin and I send x requests to show the main page of my app.

My code is as below:

```
    var taskcoll = _mainArticlesAppService.GetWelcomeStartColl().ContinueWith(async (res) =>
        {
            _applicationContext.Categories = res.Result.Categories;
        });

        var taskheros = _mainArticlesAppService.GetWelcomeHerosProfileDto().ContinueWith((res) =>
        {
            _applicationContext.HerosProfileDto = res.Result;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => HerosProfileDto);
        });

        List<Task> tasksInit = new List<Task>();

        tasksInit.Add(taskcoll);
        tasksInit.Add(taskheros);

        await Task.WhenAll(tasksInit).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When there are no issues everything is fine and works.

However when the request can't connect to the remote api server it throws ecxeption in my code and then deadlock I can't do anymore stuff and my screen is frozen.

My code where the deadlock happens is:

```
 protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int count = 0;

       using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                
                 response = await base.SendAsync(request, cts.Token);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               
                throw ex; // --> Deadlock
            }
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized &&
                HasBearerAuthorizationHeader(request))
            {
                return await HandleUnauthorizedResponse(request, response, cancellationToken);
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix `async/await` with continuations, it makes the code unpredictable.

Also without continuations the code looks better:

```csharp
var taskcoll = _mainArticlesAppService.GetWelcomeStartColl(); // start 1st request
var taskheros = _mainArticlesAppService.GetWelcomeHerosProfileDto(); // start 2nd request
// both requests are already running
_applicationContext.Categories = (await taskcoll).Categories; // await 1st request
_applicationContext.HerosProfileDto = await taskheros; // await 2nd one
RaisePropertyChanged(() => HerosProfileDto);
```

Also try this

```csharp
response = await base.SendAsync(request, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

For `throw ex` ensure that you have the `Exception` handled with `try-catch` outside of the request. As you rethrow the `Exception` as it is and don't do anything else, here inside of `SendAsync` you don't need a `try-catch` at all.

---

Here's an abstract example with multiple async calls that returns data with different delay. With no return type but typed Actions to make a callback. This approach as for me the most accurate to receive the different typed data as soon as possible by completion of each request.

```csharp
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeController controller = new SomeController();
        await controller.LoadAllData();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }  
}

public class SomeController
{
    private FirstDataClass _firstProperty;
    private SecondDataClass _secondProperty;
    private ThirdDataClass _thirdProperty;

    public FirstDataClass FirstProperty
    {
        get => _firstProperty;
        set
        {
            _firstProperty = value;
            Console.WriteLine("First data received");
        }
    }

    public SecondDataClass SecondProperty
    {
        get => _secondProperty;
        set
        {
            _secondProperty = value;
            Console.WriteLine("Second data received");
        }
    }
       
    public ThirdDataClass ThirdProperty
    {
        get => _thirdProperty;
        set
        {
            _thirdProperty = value;
            Console.WriteLine("Third data received");
        }
    }

    public async Task LoadAllData()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(GetFirstData(data => FirstProperty = data));
        tasks.Add(GetSecondData(data => SecondProperty = data));
        tasks.Add(GetThirdData(data => ThirdProperty = data));
        Console.WriteLine("Tasks launched");
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task GetFirstData(Action<FirstDataClass> action)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        action(new FirstDataClass());
    }

    private async Task GetSecondData(Action<SecondDataClass> action)
    {
        await Task.Delay(300);
        action(new SecondDataClass());
    }

    private async Task GetThirdData(Action<ThirdDataClass> action)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        action(new ThirdDataClass());
    }
}

public class FirstDataClass { }

public class SecondDataClass { }

public class ThirdDataClass { }
```

Console output

```
Tasks launched
Second data received
Third data received
First data received
```

If you don't want to change the API calling methods, you may use this approach for wrappers of that methods like:

```csharp
private async Task GetSomeData(Action<SomeType> action)
{
    action(await SomeApiCall());
}
```

Or some Generic wrapper

```csharp
private async Task GetDataWrapper<T>(Func<Task<T>> method, Action<T> action)
{
    action(await method);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where should I call the Task.WhenAll? After the taskheros? If I do this I will have to wait all the tasks completed before showing the results. Correct? My goal to do multiple requests is to show the results retrieved on my mobile screen once the request is finished. Even if the others are not.

Comment: @dalton5 you don't need a `Task.WhenAll` here, both `await`s are already inline.

Comment: @dalton5 To make that possible without complicated casts all the requests should be of the same return type. To update the data as soon as request was received `Task.WhenAll` is not suitable for you but `Task.WhenAny` is.

Comment: Ok but in your reponse you provide I think you missed the await? It should be: var taskcoll = await _mainArticlesAppService.GetWelcomeStartColl(); Correct?

Comment: @dalton5 No, two `await` calls there, all fine. :)

Comment: @dalton5 `var` is misleading you but i don't know the real return type, but you can insert the code in the project, put cursor on `var` keyword and hit `Ctrl+.` to call refactoring menu and select `Use explicit type` there.

Comment: @dalton5 I've added some comments to the code to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks. it's clearer. I am working on the solution with WhenAny and see how to improve. Will post my solution if it works. thanks

Comment: @dalton5 i can show you the solution if you tell me the return types of that two `async` methods. Or can show some abstract example.

Comment: GetWelcomeStartColl return Task<List<string>> and GetWelcomeHerosProfileDto returns Task<Heros> heros class. has a string Name property and an int id.

Comment: @dalton5 consider an abstract example in the answer. I have this approach working in use with ~50 different API calls at once.

Comment: @dalton5 any news?